# Returning UIAlertController from var

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to return an alert controller using a computed property, however i am receiving the error "Cannot convert value of type '() -> _' to specified type 'UIAlertController'" I am pretty new to iOS development after coming from C development and I hope someone could explain weere I'm going wrong. Code sample below :

```
@objc func saveButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem){
    var displayErrorController: UIAlertController = {
        let controller = UIAlertController(title: "Field not valid !",
                                           message: "Please fill out form",
                                           preferredStyle: .alert)
        controller.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .ok, handler: nil))
        return controller
    }
    form.rows.forEach({
        if !$0.wasChanged {
            self.present(displayErrorController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }

    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning the variable a block that returns a `UIAlertController` but you're not executing it.

```
var displayErrorController: UIAlertController = {
    let controller = UIAlertController(title: "Field not valid !",
                                       message: "Please fill out form",
                                       preferredStyle: .alert)
    controller.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .ok, handler: nil))
    return controller
}()
```

If you want to keep it as a computed property though, you need to change the property type to `var displayErrorController: (UIAlertController) -> () = { ... }`

Comment: Thanks so much ! I understand now !